# Mvn is not recognized as a command on Github Actions on Windows a self hosted runner

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, github-actions, windows-virtual-pc

I set up a simple Github Actions workflow simply to check if my self-hosted Windows Virtual Machine is able to recognize the installed java/git/maven versions.

**Versions in the Virtual Machine**:

- Microsoft Windows 64 bit
- Java version: jdk1.8.0_202
- Maven version: 3.8.5

Java and Git are correctly recognized however the step checking for maven version fails:

```
mvn -version
```

it fails with the following log:

```html
mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\action-runner\_work\_temp\03b2e64a-9586-4937-b61c-90e0bb0a5d9c.ps1:2 char:1
+ mvn -version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mvn:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Below how I set up the environmental variables on the machine:

[Environment Variable Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApvMX.png)

On the machine mvn command is recognized without any problems, the issue only happens when running the Github workflow yaml.
Below the .yaml script also with different attempts to set the enviroment variable from the script itself:

```html
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]


  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, selenium-1]

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Attempt 1: FAILS with mvn not recognized log
      - name: Check Maven version
        run: mvn -version

      # Attempt 2: DOES NOT FAIL but it also doesn't do anything (tried other mvn commands and nothing happened)
      - name: Check Maven Version
        run: C:\action-runner\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin\mvn -version

      # Attempt 3 set Maven as env variable with powershell and FAILS with mvn not recognized log
      - name: Set maven path as Env variable
        run: $Env:GITHUB_ENV += ';C:\action-runner\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin'

      # after Attempt 3 launched the mvn command to check if it worked but still failed
      - name: Check Maven version
        run: mvn -version

      # Attempt 4 try to set PATH variable once in the workflow with following log:
      # Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
      # Error: Invalid environment variable format 'C:\action-runner\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin'
      - name: set PATH Maven
        run: echo "C:\action-runner\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
```

Thanks in advance to anyone suggesting a solution.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error if you log in to that VM and run the command manually? Also, do you know about mvnw (maven wrapper)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this Actions from the GitHub Marketplace inside the .yml workflow file:

https://github.com/stCarolas/setup-maven
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-maven

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with python. I had install it for all users in the windows installer settings. I would try to install for all users and then the service should have maven in scope.